# Rails Actioncable success callback

Tags: callback, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I use the perform javascript call to perform an action on the server, like this:

```
subscription.perform('action', {...});
```

However, from what I've seen there seems to be no builtin javascript "success" callback, i.e. to let me know the action is concluded on the server's side (or possibly failed). I was thinking about sending a broadcast at the end of the action like so:

```
def action(data)
  ...do_stuff
  ActionCable.server.broadcast "room", success_message...
end
```

But all clients subscribed to this "room" would receive that message, possibly resulting in false positives. In addition, from what I've heard, message order isn't guaranteed, so a previous broadcast inside this action could be delivered after the success message, possibly leading to further issues.

Any ideas on this or am I missing something completely?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at https://github.com/xtian/action-cable-js/blob/master/dist/cable.js and , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#send(), `perform` just executes `WebSocket.send()` and returns true or false, and there is no way to know whether your data has arrived. (That is just not possible with WebSockets, it seems.)

You could try using just a http call (I recommend setting up an api with jbuilder), or indeed broadcasting back a success message.

You can solve the order of the messages by creating a timestamp on the server, and sending it along with the message, and then sorting the messages with Javascript.

Good luck!

Comment: I agree, mutating models with a RESTful API and then broadcasting the updates to clients seems a more stable way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for is the **trasmit** method: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3/classes/ActionCable/Channel/Base.html#method-i-transmit

It sends a message to the current connection being handled for a channel.